# What regular expression can validate this type of string?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I validate this using a regex in js?

```
first.last.wrt
```

OR

```
first.last
```

Both are part of email addresses, only the name part in the format mentioned above should validated.

Ex: These should validate using the regex:

```
john.doe.wrt
john.doe
```

Comment: Can you post examples of what _shouldn't_ validate? What is the pattern here?

Comment: It's the first part of the email address. So therefore, @ is not a valid character. Any other invalid characters that could be used in the first part of the email address is not valid.

Comment: So you just want to validate any email addresses? No specific pattern or format requirements?

Comment: @user730108: `@` may not be a valid character for your particular use, but as long as it's quoted, it's valid according to the RFCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(\.wrt)?$/
```

Based on your example, this would work.

Comment: That won't match capital letters. I know it wasn't specified, but if you can match "joe", there's no reason you can't match "Joe", as well. You should also make the last capture group a non-capture group since there's no point in saving it. You use `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`.

Comment: The examples posted doesn't work. I used the .net regular expression validator and put "/^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(\.wrt)?$/" in the expression to validate property but it says john.doe.ctr is invalid?

Comment: @SpikeX: Thanks for the feedback, but I only gave the minimum regex for the examples given.  Anything more would be assumptions on our part. :)

Comment: @user730108: That's because `ctr` does not match `wrt`.  You should give a much better description of what is and isn't valid in your question if you want a better answer.

Comment: It should match the first part of a email address (so everything before @). It should not match @ because that's not a valid in the first part of the email address.

Comment: @user730108: "The first part of an email address" is very vague.  Valid according to what?  The RFCs?  If so, then you're looking at a page-long regular expression.

Comment: @user730108: ...and yes, `@` is valid in the first part of an email address according to the RFCs, as long as it is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want letters/numbers/underscores to validate:

```
(\w+?)\.(\w+?)(?:\.wrt)?
```

If you want *anything* to validate in the "first" and "last" parts:

```
(.+?)\.(.+?)(?:\.wrt)?
```

Capture Groups:

1. First Name
2. Last Name

Comment: A non-greedy modifier is unnecessary on the first one because `.` is not part of `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(\.wrt)?$/i.test('the string')) {
    // It validates!
} else {
    // It doesn't...
}
```

I take it apostrophes and such aren't allowed, but you can add them within the square brackets.

Comment: Why not use `\w` instead? `[A-Za-z]` is pretty much identical to `\w`.

Comment: @SpikeX: Because you can't have digits or underscores in any name in any language I know of?

Comment: `\w` encompasses more than just `[A-Za-z]` (I believe `_` characters?)

Comment: I was unmarked as the answer for a less complete answer that uses the *exact same regular expression as mine* but came in a minute later? What?